# What does the time measurement in Firefox console measure specefically?

Tags: http, firefox, networking

If you go to Facebook.

```
[19:35:16.999] GET https://www.facebook.com/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 257ms]
```

If you go to Twitter,

```
[19:36:42.307] GET https://twitter.com/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 240ms]
```

If you go to my entry-level hosted site(godaddy, etc.)

```
[19:37:12.443] GET http://boomaamama.com/dev/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 150ms]
```

Here is SO:

```
[19:42:19.759] GET http://stackoverflow.com/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 117ms]
```

bit.ly

```
[20:13:46.851] GET https://bitly.com/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 88ms]
```

I found it strange that my site was faster and thought perhaps it was because I don't understand what this initial get request is measuring.

Is it measuring the download time of the initial html/css blob...i.e. index.htm...or rout_to_here.php?

Or is it measuring something else?

Is it primarily location based and not service-level based?

Comment: your tests are incorrect - HTTPS will always take longer than HTTP

Comment: @Elliot - it does not include images as those are completely separate get requests

Comment: I think it is a combo of (1)http/https, (2)site-size, and (3)host provider.  I would also like to ass-sume that it is not just the response time, but the download time as well to make (2) true.

Comment: https encodes all text not just the text you need secured....kind of a waste of processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's measuring the total time needed for that single request, i.e. the HTML document for the page itself.

The time may include:

- DNS lookup
- Connecting
- Sending
- Waiting
- Receiving

If you get the FireBug plugin, you can use the Net tab to see each request in detail, including the time for each of those steps.